# DotNet - What is int*?

Tags: c#, .net, pointers

simple question, I import a DLL function and the parameter are int*.
When I try to enter Method(0), I get an error which says: "int and int* can not convert".

What is that meaning?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

That is classic C notation for a `pointer to an int`. Whenever a type is followed by a `*`, it denotes that type as a [pointer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y31yhkeb.aspx) to that type. In C#, unlike in C, you must explicitly define functions as `unsafe` to use pointers, in addition to enabling [unsafe](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/chfa2zb8(VS.71).aspx) code in your project properties. A pointer type is also not directly interchangeable with a concrete type, so the reference of a type must be taken first. To get a pointer to another type, such as an int, in C# (or C & C++ for that matter), you must use the dereference operator `&` (ampersand) in front of the variable you wish to get a pointer to:

```
unsafe
{
    int i = 5;
    int* p = &i;
    // Invoke with pointer to i
    Method(p);
}
```

**'Unsafe' code C#**

Below are some key articles on unsafe code and the use of pointers in C#.

- [Unsafe contexts](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa664770(v=VS.71).aspx)
- [Pointer Types](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa664771(v=VS.71).aspx)
- [Fixed and movable variables](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa664772(v=VS.71).aspx)
- [Pointer conversions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa664773(v=VS.71).aspx)
- [Pointers in expressions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa664774(v=VS.71).aspx)
- [The 'fixed' statement](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa664784(v=VS.71).aspx)
- [Stack allocation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa664785(v=VS.71).aspx)
- [Dynamic memory allocation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa664786(v=VS.71).aspx)

Comment: @Nate: Good point, I'll add a better explanation of the dereference operator.

Comment: Same comment here: it has nothing to do with unsafe code.  The argument is simply passed by reference.  The "ref" keyword in C#.  It is a pointer in C# as well by the time the JIT compiler is done with it.

Comment: @Hans: The question was "What is int*?". I was providing an answer to that question...not an answer about the semantics of passing variables in different ways.

Answer (score 6):

It's a [pointer to an int](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/pcurnow/usingpointers10022007082330AM/usingpointers.aspx). Generally best avoided in managed code. You might want to post your imported method declaration. An IntPtr is usually sufficient for this kind of interop.

Comment: It is just an argument that's passed by reference.  It is well support by the P/Invoke marshaller, using IntPtr is a mistake.

Comment: Depends what it does. If it's an array, `int[]` is what you want. If it's a handle, `IntPtr` usually is best, especially if you plan on passing 0. If you want an actual reference to an int, `ref int` or `out int` might work better.

Comment: Without seeing the method declaration I wouldn't be able to guess one way or the other (ref vs array vs pointer). @Blindy is right on the money. Depends on the method being called. SendMessage's LPARAM for instance is usually marshalled as an IntPtr and that guy typically holds a memory pointer (which can be expressed as int*)

Answer (score 2):

It depends on the language you use.  In C#, you should declare the argument with the "ref" keyword.  In VB.NET you should use the ByRef keyword.  And you need to call it by passing a variable, not a constant.  Something like this:

```
 int retval = 0;
 Method(ref retval);
 // Do something with retval
 //...
```

Comment: Is ref practically the same as the & used in the accepted answer?

Comment: Under the hood after the jitter is done with it, yes.

Comment: If the authors of the DLL he used decided on the C# signature `Method(int* p)`, then he cannot invoke the method with the syntax `Method(ref retval);` you propose, right? The authors of the DLL _could_ have chosen a signature `Method(ref int p)` instead, but for some reason they did not. C# does not offer "arithmetic" on variables of type `ref int`, such as incrementation to the "next" address, the way it does with pointers `int* p` (like C# `p++` and others, "unsafe").