# what is this weird syntax in C# byte*

Tags: c#, .net, pointers

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [DotNet - What is int* ?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3238512/dotnet-what-is-int)

hi, I was viewing some source code for a library and I saw this `byte*`, what is the star at the end ?? , not only with the class byte, also with some variables name like

```
var1 = *var3 - *var2;
```

thanks in advance

Comment: Somebody help me find the existing question, I'm sure this is a dupe...

Comment: @Ben Voigt : Nice find, even if C# made search engines evolve to include the "#" symbol "*" is still ignored even in SO search :D

Answer (score 7):

It's a [pointer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y31yhkeb.aspx) (to a byte).

Comment: Well, technically, it's not a pointer per se, but a dereference operation...

Comment: @Mehrdad: The question says "I saw this `byte*`, what is the star at the end?"  That most certainly means *pointer*, not *dereference*.

Comment: @Mehrdad: i guess that he was answering to the question title, not the "also" sample part.

Answer (score 3):

When `*` is used on a data type, it's a pointer to that type. `byte*` is a pointer to a byte.

When used on a variable it will dereference the pointer. The value of `var3` is the pointer, and the value of `*var3` is the byte (or whatever type) that the pointer is pointing to.

Answer (score 0):

I'am pretty sure its [Unsafe](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/chfa2zb8%28v=VS.100%29.aspx) code.

Comment: right , the method have the keyword unsafe