# question mark inside C# syntax

Tags: c#

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Benefits of using the conditional ?: (ternary) operator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3312786/benefits-of-using-the-conditional-ternary-operator)

hi, I'm viewing this freesource library and I saw this weird - at least for me -  syntax

```
*currFrame = ( ( diff >= differenceThreshold ) || ( diff <= differenceThresholdNeg ) ) ? (byte) 255 : (byte) 0;
```

*currFrame is of type byte*

diff, differenceThreshold and differenceThresholdNeg are of type Int.

What does the question mark do ? , what is this weird assign sentence suppose to mean ?

Thanks in advance

Comment: The star-sign (*) in `*currFrame` is a lot weirder (in C#).

Comment: right, [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5136293/what-is-this-weird-syntax-in-c-byte)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The **conditional operator** (?:) returns one of two values depending on the value of a Boolean expression. Following is the syntax for the conditional operator.

```
condition ? first_expression : second_expression;
```

**C# reference: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ty67wk28.aspx**

In your case currFrame will be assigned a value of 255 if `( diff >= differenceThreshold ) || ( diff <= differenceThresholdNeg )` is `true`, otherwise value 0 will be assigned.

Answer (score 7):

this is the same as

```
if(( diff >= differenceThreshold ) || ( diff <= differenceThresholdNeg ) )
     currFrame = (byte) 255
else
    currFrame = (byte) 0
```

Answer (score 4):

It is the [conditional operator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ty67wk28%28VS.80%29.aspx).

Comment: Its *name* is the conditional operator though. It happens to be the only ternary operator currently in C#, but it's worth calling it by its name rather than just identifying it by the number of operands, IMO.

Comment: It is *a* ternary operator. It's specifically the conditional operator. Whilst, at present, C# exposes only a single ternary operator, you wouldn't go around referring to `+` as "the binary operator"

Comment: I'll bow to peer pressure and put conditional.

Answer (score 3):

[?: Operator (C# Reference)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ty67wk28%28v=vs.80%29.aspx):

The conditional operator (?:) returns one of two values depending on the value of a Boolean expression. The conditional operator is of the form

```
condition ? first_expression : second_expression;
```

Answer (score 1):

'?:' is a conditional operator, you can read about it here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ty67wk28(v=vs.80).aspx

Answer (score 0):

This is a *ternary* operator (see [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ty67wk28%28v=VS.100%29.aspx)). It follows the following syntax:

```
result = condition ? result_if_condition_true : result_if_condition_false
```

Comment: It's a ternary operator *called* the conditional operator.

Answer (score 0):

```
if ( diff >= differenceThreshold ) || ( diff <= differenceThresholdNeg ) ) 
*currFrame = (byte) 255;
else *currFrame =  (byte) 0;
```